# Fallo el generar gráfica (Laravel con Highcharts)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

Estoy usando Laravel 4.2, hago una conexión a mi base de datos MySQL.

Mi controlador tiene el siguiente código

```
public function highcharts(){
    //Consulta que me trae el sexo y la cantidad de registros con ese mismo sexo
    $canti = DB::table('Personas')
                        ->select(DB::raw('sexo as sexo, count(sexo) as cantidad'))
                        ->groupBy('sexo')
                        ->get();
                        //propiedades necesarias para crear la gráfica
                        $chartArray["chart"] = array("type" => "column");
                        $chartArray["title"] = array("text" => "Relación de Sexos - Femenino/Masculino");
                        $chartArray["subtitle"] = array("text" => "Exposición");
                        $chartArray["credits"] = array("enabled" => false);
                        $chartArray["navigation"] = array("buttonOptions" => array("align" => "left"));
                        $chartArray["series"] = array();
                        $chartArray["xAxis"] = array("categories" => array());
                        foreach ($canti as $user)
                        {
                          $categoryArray[] = $user->sexo;

                          $chartArray["series"][] = array("name" => $user->sexo, "data" => array(count($user->sexo)) );

                        }

                        $chartArray["xAxis"] = array("categories" => $categoryArray);
                        $chartArray["yAxis"] = array("title" => array("text" => "Total de Personas"));

                        return View::make('highcharts.highcharts_example')->with("chartArray", $chartArray);
}
```

Mi archivo .blade.php tiene esto, exporto el JS de highcharts sin problemas. (si tengo un div con id "container", aclaro)

```
{{ HTML::script('https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js') }}

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts(
        {{json_encode($chartArray)}}
    )
    });
    </script>
```

Mi consulta mediante Laravel me trae esto:

> [{"sexo":"Femenino","cantidad":"6"},{"sexo":"Masculino","cantidad":"5"}]

Y la gráfica resultante es:
[image: Femenino y Masculino bien, pero los valores son 6 y 5, no 1 y 1 como muestra]

Deduzco que por lógica mi error es aquí:

```
$chartArray["series"][] = array("name" => $user->sexo, "data" => array(count($user->sexo)) );
```

Ya que, en "name" me consigue tras cada "pasada" del foreach el valor, femenino y luego masculino, pero en donde va "data", lo lógico sería poner más bien:

```
array($user->cantidad)
```

No obtengo ningún resultado, cual podría ser el error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tú mismo indicas, en esta línea de código hay un error:

```
$chartArray["series"][] = array("name" => $user->sexo, "data" => array(count($user->sexo)) );
```

El problema es que `$user->sexo` es una cadena de texto (Femenino/Masculino) y no un objeto o array, entonces cuando haces `count($user->sexo)` siempre vas a obtener 1. Esto se debe a que `count` funciona así para variables "no contables", como se puede leer en la [documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.count.php) (énfasis mío):

> count — Cuenta todos los elementos de un array o algo de un objeto
>
> [...]
>
> Devuelve el número de elementos en array_or_countable, **Si el parámetro no es un array o no es un objecto con la interfaz Countable implementada, devolverá 1**. Existe una excepción, si array_or_countable es NULL, devolverá 0.

En lugar de usar `$user->sexo` deberías usar `$user->cantidad` y, si no me equivoco, no necesitarías convertirlo en un array para pasarselo a Highcharts, simplemente tendrías que pasar el valor. Entonces, prueba algo como esto que ya debería mostrar la gráfica correcta:

```
$chartArray["series"][] = array("name" => $user->sexo, "data" => $user->cantidad );
```

Comment: Era algo parecido a eso, pero tal vez no del todo :'s

Así lo pude solucionar:
              $arrayChart["series"][] = array("name" => $user->Sexo, "data" => array(doubleval($user->Cantidad)) );